# Custom select with css not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I wish to change the button (arrow down) in the right corner of the select box. My html is like this:

```
<div class="buscaSelect">
    <select name="oper">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Than the CSS:

```
.buscaSelect {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 18px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 27px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white url("btnSelect.png") no-repeat right center;
}

.buscaSelect select {
    padding: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

In Safari, the result is perfect, the default button is changed by "btnSelect.png", but in Firefox (58.0b9), the default button is still there, overlapping my button. As the default button got smaller width, the corner of my button is appearing behind... the result is terrible!

How can I deactivate the Firefox default button and show only mine?

Comment: Hint: `-webkit-appearance` only applies to WebKit-based browsers (Chrome, Safari). You need to use the Gecko/Mozilla equivalent for Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance

Comment: @Dai For firefox, there's -moz-appearance provided as well. You can look at my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this, hope it helps. I have given the comparison of both with dropdown and without dropdown arrow side by side.The webkit-appearance:none works well with firefox and chrome but for IE you might need to use this:

```
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

```css
.buscaSelect {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 18px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 120px;
    height: 27px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white url("btnSelect.png") no-repeat right center;
}

.buscaSelect select {
    padding: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#noarrow {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 1px;
    text-overflow: '';
}
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="buscaSelect">
    <select name="oper" id="noarrow">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="buscaSelect">
    <select name="oper">
        <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
        <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: So the mozilla equivalent code for webkit was missing! But there is no need of that #noarrow, besides, the point is to create a class of select, can't be done with specific id. Also, I think we should include the ms equivalent, I bet there is one...

Comment: That was an example to demonstrate you. There isn't any need but I wanted to show the difference for different browsers of how it is being rendered.

Comment: And if you did notice, I did include it at the top: select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}

Comment: @Gustavo If this solution helped you, make sure to mark it up. Cheers